# rails api with mongodb raising exception for rails g command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, api, rails-api

I am developing a rails-api application using mongodb as a database.

I have executed following commands to initiate api development:-

`rails-api new wiz-diary-api --skip-active-record --skip-sprockets`

`bundle install`

`rails g mongoid:config`

but the last command raises an error. Since using `skip-active-record` command does not generate and so not needed to generate database.yml. Then why, it is still asking for database.yml file.

```
/home/user/.gem/ruby/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:139:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
```

I need some help in solving the problem. 
Thank you

Comment: `rails-api` was ported into rails 5 the syntax is `rails new [app_name] [options] --api` e.g. `rails new wiz-diary-api --skip-active-record --skip-sprockets --api.` secondly try supplying database_name to  the mongoid generator as right now it is trying to infer it through the application and I think this is your main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the heading "Getting Rid of Active Record" in the official documentation, should solve your issue.

[Mongoid Documentation](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html)